# How to change to color of react-native-tab-view?

Tags: react-native, react-native-tab-view

I am new to react-native and learning it. While learning react-native-tab-view, I tried to change it's color but after several tries I was unable to do it. I shall be really grateful if someone guide me how to change to color of the tab-bar which is blue by-default. [Here is the link to npm react-native-tab-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view) and here is the piece of code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TabView, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';
 
const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }]} />
);
 
const SecondRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }]} />
);
 
const initialLayout = { width: Dimensions.get('window').width };
 
export default function TabViewExample() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'first', title: 'First' },
    { key: 'second', title: 'Second' },
  ]);
 
  const renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: SecondRoute,
  });
 
  return (
    <TabView
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={initialLayout}
    />
  );
}
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scene: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Changing the background color of the tab-bar**

If you refer to this [section](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view#rendertabbar), the styling props for the tab-bar will have to be passed after declaring a custom React component using the `renderTabBar` prop.

```
<TabView
  navigationState={{ index, routes }}
  renderScene={renderScene}
  onIndexChange={setIndex}
  initialLayout={initialLayout}
  renderTabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}/>} // <-- add this line
/>
```

**Changing the text color of the tab-bar**

If you refer to this,

```
<TabBar
  renderLabel={({route, color}) => (
    <Text style={{ color: 'black', margin: 8 }}>
      {route.title}
    </Text>
  )}
  style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
  ...
/>
```

Feel free to experiment further using the [example snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/react-native-tab-view-quick-start). :)

Comment: What if I want to change the color of text as well? i.e. I want to change FIRST, SECOND and THIRD to black. How this can be done?

Comment: @DilawerHussain you will have to use the `renderLabel` prop to add a `Text` component. see my updated answer as an example.

Comment: i need to change custom hover color. as it is shown yellow! how can i change it?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Here is my implementation of how I achieved it**

customize the TabBar then use it in the TabView like below code

first thing first let's initialize the states first

```
   const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
   const [routes] = useState([
     { key: 'first', title: 'Main Tab' },
     { key: 'second', title: 'Second Tab' }]);

   const renderScene = SceneMap({
     first: FeaturedStore,
     second: AllStore });
```

to change the style of the labels/titles this might help you.
here I have used my custom TextView you can use your own

```
 const renderTabBar = props => {
    return (
      <TabBar
        {...props}
        renderLabel={({ focused, route }) => {
          return (
            <TextView
              size={20}
              category="Medium"
              color={focused ? 'BLACK' : 'GRAY3'}>
              {route.title}
            </TextView>
          );
        }}
        indicatorStyle={styles.indicatorStyle}
        style={styles.tabBar}
      />
    );
  };
```

this is the sample code for TabView

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.divider} />
    <TabView
      renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH }}
      showPageIndicator={true}
    />
  </View>
```

Let's put the cherry on the cake below is the styling making this TabView looks like this

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: COLORS.WHITE },
  tabBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: COLORS.BLACK,
  },
  indicatorStyle: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.PRIMARY,
    padding: 1.5,
    marginBottom: -2,
  },
  divider: {
    zIndex: 100,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 1,
    height: 48,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
});
```

for further information, you can visit official [docs](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view#readme)

Answer (score 2):

```
import { TabBar } from 'react-native-tab-view';

...

<TabView
  renderTabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} />}
  ...
/>
```

By this way you can change your color of tab bar
dont forget to import `TabBar`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom [react-native-tab-view-custom-tabbar](https://snack.expo.io/@satya164/react-native-tab-view-custom-tabbar)

More details here [react-native-tab-view#readme](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view#readme)